# Getting 401 unauthorized error when trying authenticate user in SPO using MSAL

Tags: azure-active-directory, salesforce, azure-ad-msal, salesforce-lightning

Has anyone worked on Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL V2.0)?
MSAL Link: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser

Scenario:
Users are using Microsoft credentials to access all the applications using SSO. We are planning to create a custom component in salesforce for SharePoint which allows basic actions (view/ update/ delete). We are trying to implement a solution to authenticate into SPO using SSO login from Microsoft account in Salesforce. I am trying to authenticate SharePoint URL from Salesforce. I have set up a Microsoft Azure application. Using MSAL, I am able to get the access token for the current logged-in Microsoft user account in Salesforce. When I try to authenticate SharePoint URL with an access token, I am getting 401 unauthorized error.

Does anyone have any idea about this? I am wondering if I need to do any application-specific changes in the Microsoft Azure application. Thanks.

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: It's confidential information, so I can not provide the screenshots. Are you looking for any specific information?

Comment: Then you provide `aud` claim.

Comment: Access Token's Audience is set to Microsoft Graph(https://graph.microsoft.com).

Comment: Okay, that's the problem, you are using the token of ms graph api to call SharePoint api so you get a 401 error.

Comment: What is the api you are calling?  Provide it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you cannot use the token of ms graph api to call **SharePoint** api, so try to change the `scope` to: `https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/.default`.

Parse the token and look at the `aud` claim, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I am getting below scope in response when I request for an access token.

scopes":["AllSites.Read","AllSites.Write","Directory.Read.All","openid","profile","Sites.Read.All","Sites.ReadWrite.All","Sites.Search.All","User.Read","email"]

When I set the scope to SharePoint link + './default', I am getting an error as ".default scope can't be combined with resource-specific scopes.".
Where do I need to set the default scope?

Comment: MSAL library is populating scope based on permissions in the Azure application. How can I include default access in the Azure application?

Comment: @Mrunali70  You don't need to put in the extra scope, because you only need to request the SharePoint access token, so you only need to put in `https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/.default`. Please note that do not put into the scope of ms graph api, this may cause conflicts.

Comment: I have added .default scope and I am getting aud as SharePoint URL I am still getting 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: @Mrunali70  Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.  What is the api you are calling? Provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Carl for the help. I reached out to the Microsoft team. The Microsoft team created appinv settings in SharePoint which grants permission to the azure application. This configuration resolved the 401 error.

Comment: How do you set up the `scope`?