# Getting 401 unauthorized when trying to access secured Web API using MSAL, OpenID Connect

Tags: .net, openid, azure-ad-msal

I need to access secured Web API (hosted on Azure) from my client application.
When I open my client application I am retrieving Access token which then I'm adding to request header, but API returns `401 unauthorized`.

## This is how I get access token on Client

```
public async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            var authorizationUri = new Uri($@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AUTHORITY}");
            var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(CLIENTID)
               .WithAuthority(authorizationUri)
               //.WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount)
               .WithRedirectUri(REDIRECTURL).Build();

            // 2. GetAccounts
            var accounts = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();
            var accountToLogin = PublicClientApplication.OperatingSystemAccount;
            try
            {
                // 3. AcquireTokenSilent 
                var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenSilent(new[] { "api://..api-id../access_as_user" }, accountToLogin) 
                .ExecuteAsync();                

                return authResult.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException) 
            {
                // 5. AcquireTokenInteractive
                var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(new[] { "api://..api-id../access_as_user" }) 
                .WithAccount(accountToLogin)  
                .ExecuteAsync();

                return authResult.AccessToken;
            }
        }
```

## This is how I call Web API

```
public async Task<string> GetForecast()
{
    var access = new ServiceAccess();
    var token = await access.GetToken();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://my-api.azurewebsites.net/api/weatherforecast");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    ...
}
```

## This is authentication configuration for the web api

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "mypolicy",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

When I check content of token in jwt.io I don't see anything wrong with it.

```
{
  "aud": "my web API id",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tenant-id/v2.0",
  "iat": 1675018002,
  "nbf": 1675018002,
  "exp": 1675022027,
  "aio": "....",
  "azp": "my web API id",
  "azpacr": "0",
  "idp": "live.com",
  "name": "...",
  "oid": "some guid",
  "preferred_username": "...@gmail.com",
  "rh": "???",
  "scp": "access_as_user",
  "sub": "???",
  "tid": "my tenant id",
  "uti": "???",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

Found some similar post in SO, but none of them seemed to reference my issue

1. [Wrong audience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666289/getting-401-unauthorized-error-when-trying-authenticate-user-in-spo-using-msal) - in my case Token's audience contains Web API's ID
2. [Tried this manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-api-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet)

Comment: not very sure about if it's a request header issue. We should have a "blank" between Bearer and token like `Bearer xxxx`.https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xTy9.png

Comment: By the way this is the token I generate to call API: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3LwL.png

Comment: @TinyWang the blank is added automatically, and after adding JwtBearerOption.IncludeErrorDetail=true I've got Bearer error=`invalid_token`, error_description=`The signature is invalid`, but for now I can't find what is wrong. Can you suggest what should I check?

Comment: checking the scopes you used for generating the access token, or the configuration in your api project which used to validate the token. when generating the token, my code is `await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "api://azure_Ad_client_id_exposing_api/Tiny.Read" });`, and for the api project, the audience configuration is `"Audience": "api://azure_Ad_client_id_exposing_api"`. And I used only one Azure AD app, so other configurations about client id is the same as `azure_Ad_client_id_exposing_api`, if you have 2 aad apps, then the client id should be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that issue was with registration in **Azure App registrations** for my API.

I needed to select "**Access Token**"! When I did that my authentication started to work
[image]

After that this is the explanation that I found (couldn't find it before)
Access Tokens are used to secure access to resources, e.g. API, for the API to work correctly you need to configure your app registration in Azure AD to issue access tokens

P.S. With previous API (.NET framework) I had only ID token in the app registration and it did work, but probably that is because I used it differently on client side - creating ServiceClientCredentials and providing it as an argument to API client constructor

Answer (score 1):

One approach to debug token problems is to enable the following flag inside the AddJwtBearer options:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines whether the token validation errors should be returned to the caller. 
    /// Default set to true.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IncludeErrorDetails { get; set; } = true;
```

If set to true, it will include more error details in the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

The alternative is to look at the logs from AddJwtBearer.

To access the log files, you can change the debug level, to Debug or Trace for the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication namespace. If you configure logging from appsettings, the you can do that using:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting exactly `invalid_token` and `the signature is invalid`

Comment: If the signature is valid, that is often because you first logged in, received your tokens, but then re-deployed IdentityServer and if it generated new signing keys, then your existing tokens in the clients are no longer valid. Is this the case on your end? you need to configure IdentityServer, to remember its signing keys across re-deployments.

Comment: where/how can I get logs from AddJwtBearer?

Comment: Does my answer help your problem with the logs?